# How should i know which property comes under InputParameters Based on Message Request in Dynamics crm Plugin?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

CreateRequest Message is named Target,which is of type Entity.But not all Request contain a Target property is of type Entity.

For Example AssociateRequest InputParameter contains Relationship is of type Relationship.

For Example AddItem message will return which property?How should I know there are so many messages in plugin registration tool.how should I know which message has what property it will return.

it was only possible with Debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree there so many messages, but I had this below file with my, while developing plugin
and I look for the type of `Input parameter first`

I got this file from http://patrickverbeeten.com/Blog/2008/01/25/CRM-40-Plug-in-message-input-parameters

But I have tried to update this file somewhat for CRM 2011:

Please download file from:
      http://tempsend.com/4C08EE4EA9

Comment: Thanks for the Suggesting.I downloaded that file.

Comment: The links above don't work anymore, but they were archived [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20121102205111/http://www.patrickverbeeten.com/Blog/2008/01/25/CRM-40-Plug-in-message-input-parameters) (the file can be downloaded through this link).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct you can just do the following:

```
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target")) {
   // Do something with Target
}
else if (context.InputParameters.Contains(“Relationship”)) {
   // Do something with Relationship
}
```

If you want to confirm that Target is of Entity (I think it always is in the plugin) then I would think you could just do the following:

```
if (context.InputParameters["Target"].GetType() == new Entity().GetType()) {

}
```