# How to know what InputParameters values are possible in Dynamics CRM Plugin context?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm trying to understand the plug-in sample from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594416.aspx).
There's this condition:

```
// The InputParameters collection contains all the data passed in the message request.
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
                context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
```

Speaking generally, not just with regard to this sample, on what prior knowledge should I base my decision to access a specific property? How could I have known to test whether the `InputParameters` contains a `"Target"` key (I assume I'm not supposed to guess it)?

And on what basis could I have known to ask whether the `"Target"` mapped value is of `Entity` type, and not some other type?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545934/how-should-i-know-which-property-comes-under-inputparameters-based-on-message-re) post from 2 years ago, and I've found [this](http://mscrmuk.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/the-given-key-was-not-present-in.html) webpage, saying (emphasis is mine):

> Within a plugin, the values in context.InputParameters and
> context.OutputParameters depend on the message and the stage that you
> register the plugin on. For example, "Target" is present in
> InputParameters for the Create and Update messages, but not the
> SetState message. Also, OutputParameters only exist in a Post stage,
> and not in a Pre stage. **There is no single source of documentation
> that provides the complete set of InputParameters and OutputParameters
> by message and stage**.

From my searchings, a single source still doesn't exist, but maybe the possible values can be found using the Dynamics Online platform, somewhere deep down the Settings menu, maybe? Any source would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice for doing this is to use a strongly typed approach. If, for example, you want to know which propertes are available on a CreateRequest, you would do:

```
var createReq = new CreateRequest() { Parameters = context.InputParameters };
createReq.Target; // Has type Entity
```

Take a look at the full blog post explaining this approach: [Tip: Proper handling of Plugin InputParameters](http://mktange.com/posts/tip-plugin-inputparameters/)

---

*Original answer:*

It depends on which request we are talking about. See [Understand the data context passed to a plug-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673.aspx#Anchor_4) on MSDN.

> As an example, take a look at CreateRequest. One property of
>   CreateRequest is named Target, which is of type Entity. This is the
>   entity currently being operated upon by the platform. To access the
>   data of the entity you would use the name “Target” as the key in the
>   input parameter collection. You also need to cast the returned
>   instance.
>
> Note that not all requests contain a Target property that is of type
>   Entity, so you have to look at each request or response. For example,
>   DeleteRequest has a Target property, but its type is EntityReference.

In summary: Look at the actual request, e.g the [CreateRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.createrequest.aspx).

Comment: Well, if `"Target"` is the only property of `CreateRequest` that is relevant here (i.e., holds a reference to the entity), why then the `if` condition is needed? What may happen if it is omitted?

Comment: I do not see the _if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target")_ part being needed. A CreateRequest should always contain Target in its InputParameters.

Comment: I think the `if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target")` part is to prevent errors if you have the same code being registered for multiple request types. For example, if you register your plugin on `Retrieve` and `Create` but you want different things to happen, you could (potentially) write a single plugin for both operations

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an "old" question that already has been answered, but I think this can be helpful. I've built a small web page that contains all the messages with all the Input/Output parameters. You can access it from [here](http://fedejousset.com/parameterbrowser/):

[image]

Comment: That link is broken does anyone know if there is a address to use this tool?

Answer (score 2):

In 2011 someone actually generated typed properties based on the message type.  Kind of neat:  https://xrmpalmer.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/crm2011-plugin-inputparameter-and-outputparameter-helper/

It would show you want parameters are possible per message.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. If only we can have this applied to Dynamics 2016...

Comment: Very little has changed @HelterSkelter, and if you have an on prem version, you could run the same SQL scripts to generate a 2016 version.

Comment: I know, but I have the Online version.

Comment: I know that I'm a little late, but I've made this: 
http://fedejousset.com/parameterbrowser/

Comment: @FedericoJousset that is really nice!

Comment: U got a Twitter handle @FedericoJousset?

Comment: Hi Daryl, my twitter account is @fedejousset (but I'm not very active there though)...